# How to redefine comment character using literate

Tags: listings

I would like to render the comment character differently,
specifically I would like to render Ada's double dash as a long dash.
Using `literate=*{--}{{---}}1` achieves the mapping, but unfortunately this interferes with listings' ability to render the comment. It is no longer formated as comment. How can I achieve my goal without this side effect?

Here is some sample code demonstrating the problem:

```
 \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{listings}

 \usepackage{mathptmx}
 \usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
 \usepackage{txfonts}

 \lstset{basicstyle=\sffamily}
 \lstset{texcl}
 \lstset{literate=%
 *{:=}{{$\coloneqq$}}1
 {+}{{$+$}}1
 {:}{{$\colon$}}1
 {<=}{{$\leq$}}1
 {>=}{{$\geq$}}1
 {/=}{{$\neq$}}1
 {=}{{$=$}}1
 {=>}{{$\Rightarrow$}}1
 {--}{{---} }1
 }
 \lstset{language=Ada,tabsize=3,columns=fullflexible,showstringspaces=false,escapechar=`,keepspaces}


 \title{Test}

 \begin{document}
 \maketitle

 \section{Code Listings}

 \begin{lstlisting}
 function Perform_Operation(X: Integer);
 -- This is a comment, keywords such as begin end
 -- should not be highligted and should be in
 -- commentstyle

 \end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Welcome.  Could you provide a small sample file for testing?

Comment: `{--}{{$---$}}1` is sufficient?

Comment: No @ferahfeza, that still interferes with comment styling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the escape mechanism, e.g. via

```
escapeinside={--}{\^^M},escapebegin={--},escapeend={}
```

which captures the line from `--` to the end, typesets an endash and the comment text as ordinary LaTeX.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage{txfonts}

\lstset{language=Ada,basicstyle=\sffamily,texcl,
literate=%
*{:=}{{$\coloneqq$}}1
{+}{{$+$}}1
{:}{{$\colon$}}1
{<=}{{$\leq$}}1
{>=}{{$\geq$}}1
{/=}{{$\neq$}}1
{=}{{$=$}}1
{=>}{{$\Rightarrow$}}1,
tabsize=3,
columns=fullflexible,
showstringspaces=false,
escapechar=`,
keepspaces,
escapeinside={--}{\^^M},escapebegin={--},escapeend={}}

\title{Test}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Code Listings}

\begin{lstlisting}
function Perform_Operation(X: Integer);
-- This is a comment, keywords such as begin end
-- should not be highligted and should be in
-- commentstyle

\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

You can add further styling to the output if needed via `escapebegin`.  For example, to italic text after the dash, you can use

```
escapebegin={--\itshape}
```

[image: italic sample]

Comment: This works quite well, a minor problem I noticed is that if there is a double dash inside a string (`"something -- something"`), the escape mechanism is confused and the rest of the program is rendered in latex mode.